# Grouping values into buckets

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, join, cte

I'm working a query and I wasn't sure if my current approach is the "best" approach.
I got a table filled with values and a table with buckets that I use to group those values.

There are 2 types of buckets:

- A **priority bucket**, if items apply to the conditions they should fall in this bucket and be excluded for any following bucket.
- A simple **range bucket**, the values should fall within a range.

I set up a simplified version that can be used to test.
the `[Filter]` column in `#tempBUcket` here is used for the priority buckets

The table definitions

```
create table #TempData([Id] int, [value] int);
create table #TempBucket([Id] int, [FromVal] int,[ToVal] int,[Filter] int);
```

Some test data

```
INSERT INTO #TempData (Id,value)
    VALUES  (1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4),(5,5),
            (6,6),(7,7),(8,8),(9,9),(10,1),
            (11,2),(12,3),(13,4),(14,5),(15,6),
            (16,7),(17,8),(18,9),(19,10),(20,11);
INSERT INTO #TempBucket(Id,FromVal,ToVal,Filter)
    VALUES  (1,0,3,0),(2,3,6,0),
            (3,6,9,0),(4,9,12,0),
            (5,NULL,NULL,1),(6,NULL,NULL,2);
```

Right now I have this query which works and gives the results I want but I feel this could be done better and more efficiently.

```
WITH filteredData as 
    (SELECT tv.*,COALESCE(tb1.Id,tb2.Id) as BucketId FROM #TempData tv
    LEFT JOIN #TempBucket tb1 --prio bucket join
        ON tb1.Filter IS NOT NULL AND tb1.Filter = tv.Value
    LEFT JOIN #TempBucket tb2 --range bucket join
        ON tb2.Fromval < tv.value AND tv.value <= tb2.ToVal
    )
SELECT Count(fd.value) as count ,BucketId FROM filteredData fd GROUP BY BucketId;
```

[dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=28f4bc04556c8556f2e8a714a98760d0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution does only 1 `scan` of `#TempBucket` but it adds an additional `sort`, I'm not sure it's more efficient, you should test it on volumes of data:

```
;with cte as
(
select t.*, tb.id as BucketId,
       row_number() over(partition by t.id order by tb.FromVal) as rn
from #TempData t
     join #TempBucket tb 
         on (t.value = tb.filter)  
         or (tb.Fromval < t.value AND t.value <= tb.ToVal)
)
select count(id) as cnt, BucketId
from cte
where rn = 1
group by BucketId;
```

To give a priority to the row in `priority bucket` it sorts by `tb.FromVal` which is null in case of priority bucket, alternatively you can sort on `tb.Filter desc`, I just don't know the exact criteria of `priority bucket` whether the `FromVal,ToVal` are `null` or `Filter = 0`

Comment: I did some quick tests but so far it works amazingly! It seems like it could be about 4 times as fast as the query I had. I wouldn't have thought of this myself, thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across the same problem and this is what I created. It uses the same range left and range right logica for partitioning functions.

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.BucketValue(@bucketDefinition varchar(max), @Value int, @RangeFocus char(1) = 'L')
returns int
as
    begin
        declare @Bucket int;

        WITH cte AS (
            SELECT  value AS entity
            FROM    STRING_SPLIT(@bucketDefinition, ';')
        )
        , CTE2 as (
            select  coalesce(LAG(entity) over (order by entity), -2147483648) as previousEntity,
                    entity
            FROM    cte
            union
            SELECT  MAX(entity), 2147483647
            from    cte
        )
        , CTE3 as (
            select  *, row_number() over (order by entity) as Bucket
            FROM    cte2
        )
        select @bucket = Bucket 
        from CTE3 
        where (@value > previousEntity and @value <= Entity and @rangeFocus = 'L' )
        or (@value >= previousEntity and @value < Entity and @rangeFocus = 'R' )

        return(@bucket);
    end
go

-- example:
declare @l varchar(max) = '1;100;1000'
declare @i int = 1000
select @i, 'L', dbo.BucketValue(@l, @i, 'L')
select @i, 'R', dbo.BucketValue(@l, @i, 'R');
```